# Android NDK and .so.X extensions

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to use the Grantlee library in an Android NDK app.

I can compile Grantlee just fine, and I get `libGrantlee_Templates.so`, `libGrantlee_Templates.so.5`, and `libGrantlee_Templates.so.5.0.0`.

Of these three, I can only install the first one in my Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libgrantlee
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(GRANTLEE_PATH)/lib/libGrantlee_Templates.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Because if I try to install either of the other two, then I get:

```
Android NDK: ERROR:Android.mk:grantlee: LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with ".so"
Android NDK: The following file is unsupported: libGrantlee_Templates.so.5
```

But then, like a cruel joke, the .so.5 that I can't install is exactly the file that it looks for at runtime:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14439): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libGrantlee_Templates.so.5"; caused by library "libGrantlee_Templates.so.5" not found
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You are likely using the wrong compiler or build system.  Unlike glibc based linuxes, bionic-based android does not utilized versioned library names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a native shared library with NDK standalone toolchain, you must change its make files to get rid of `.version` suffixes. See for example how this is [done for **ffmpeg**](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using an external library in my project.

You can also add `-avoid-version` to the libtool command. This trick saved my day...

Answer (score 0):

If the library is built with an autotools/libtool based build system, update the bundled libtool to libtool 2.4.3 or newer. Those versions know how to deal with these details about android shared libraries, so if you build it with `--host=arm-linux-androideabi` or similar, it won't add any version numbers to the libraries.

To upgrade the libtool version within a source package, run e.g. `autogen.sh` or a similar script within the source package, or `autoreconf -fi`, assuming that you've got a new enough version of libtool installed in the surrounding system.